# Converting string[] form values to the required types of string and int

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, type-conversion, dbcontext

I have a HTTP Post action whereby I am posting a HttpPostedFileBase and a FormCollection as my parameters

My controller action is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult NewContent(HttpPostedFileBase postedFile,string username, FormCollection form)
    {
        if (postedFile != null)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase postedFileCopy = postedFile;
            postedFileCopy.InputStream.Position = 0;
            Stream stream = postedFile.InputStream;

            //avm.AddContent(postedFile, stream, "jpmcfeely");

            string[] name = form.GetValues("name");
            string[] author = form.GetValues("author");
            string[] description = form.GetValues("description");
            DateTime uploaddate = DateTime.Today;//form.GetValues("uploaddate");
            DateTime expirydate = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(1);//form.GetValues("expirydate");
            string[] participationpoints = form.GetValues("participationpoints");
            string[] contenttypeid = form.GetValues("contenttypeid");

            try
            {
                avm.AddContent(postedFile, stream, "jpmcfeely", name.ToString(), author.ToString(), description.ToString(), uploaddate, expirydate, Convert.ToInt32(participationpoints), Convert.ToInt32(contenttypeid));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
            }
        }
```

I then have a method in my ViewModel which adds the details of the form collection to my sql storage table as follows:

```
public void AddContent(HttpPostedFileBase content, System.IO.Stream stream, string userName, string name, string author, string description, string uploadDate, string expiryDate, int participationPoints, int contentType)
    {
        string contentUri = "";

        Content newContent = new Content();
        contentUri = Helpers.ContentUtils.AddContentToBlob(content, stream, "useravatar", content.FileName);

        newContent.Name = name;
        newContent.Author = author;
        newContent.Description = description;
        newContent.UploadDate = DateTime.Today;
        newContent.ExpiryDate = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(1);
        newContent.ParticipationPoints = 50;
        newContent.ContentBlobURL = contentUri;
        newContent.ContentTypeID = contentType;

        this.contentRepository.Add(newContent);
        this.contentRepository.SaveChanges();

    }
```

If I build the solution it compiles without error but on save of the content inside the try block on the controller I am getting the following error:

**Unable to cast object of type 'System.String[]' to type 'System.IConvertible'**

If I just pass the string values in by hardcoding then the method saves as expected so my problem is simply converting these to the appropriate format. What is best approach to do this or am I missing a step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this snippet

```
  Convert.ToInt32(participationpoints), Convert.ToInt32(contenttypeid)
```

to this

```
  Convert.ToInt32(participationpoints[0]), Convert.ToInt32(contenttypeid[0])
```

Comment: nice one buddy thanks that solves my issue good man yourself :)